# Spring Boot & MySQL can`t find the DB

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to solve this problem in my project, but it appears every time.
I have already added properties with prefix spring.datasource but it is still not working.

So can somebody help me?

I want to build web application with Spring Boot, MySQL and Hibernate.
I have not found the answer in internet.
Thanks.

```
2016-10-22 14:49:15.072 ERROR 23100 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE
Action:
If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the       classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile  you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Here is my code:

```
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>lardi</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Phone Book</name>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <start-class>com.SpringBootWebApplication</start-class>

    <!-- JSON -->
    <jackson-json.version>2.8.0</jackson-json.version>

    <!-- WEB jars -->
    <webjars-bootstrap.version>3.3.6</webjars-bootstrap.version>
    <webjars-jquery.version>2.2.4</webjars-jquery.version>
    <webjars-noty.version>2.3.8</webjars-noty.version>
    <webjars-datatables.version>1.10.12</webjars-datatables.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot WEB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Boot TEST -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Boot Validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Boot Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Boot JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-json.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-json.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-json.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Webjars -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>noty</artifactId>
        <version>${webjars-noty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
        <version>${webjars-datatables.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {Contact.class, User.class, BaseEntity.class})
public class SpringBootWebApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my properties:

```
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lardi
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=2940063
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
useSSL=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: and your properties?

Comment: sorry, i forget it. Here:

Comment: spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lardi
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=2940063
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
useSSL=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Comment: My guess is that it is not picking up your properties. Are these properties defined in `application.properties` located in `src/main/resources`?

Comment: I solved my question. The problem was in location application.properties. It was is src/main/resources.properties and should be simply in src/main/resources.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: check your property `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` there was also a mistake in the word `dialect` - you used cyrillic character `c`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Spring Boot how to connect to your database. If you've added the driver, we can't guess the location and authentication information for you. You will find more information [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database)

Try to add the following in `src/main/resources/application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
```

Of course, you'll have to adapt the name of the database (`test`) and the username/password.

Comment: No, it is still not working. I have the same exception.